# Спряжение глагола «бежать»

Tags: спряжение

Насколько я понимаю,— спряжение глагола *бежать* первое; тогда почему 
*он бежит* с окончанием 2-го спряжения? А *они бегут* с окончанием 1-го спряжения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

бежать относится к т.н. разноспрягаемым глаголам. 
[разноспрягаемый глагол](http://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=raznospriagaemie_glagoli)
Их в языке немного, в школе обычно серьёзного внимания на них не обращают, поскольку ошибок носители языка не делают.

Хотя до XIX века наряду с бегут употреблялось и бежат.

~~~

Глаголы, которые в школе называют **глаголоми-исключениями**, имеют неопределенную форму, соответствующую одному спряжению, а все личные формы - другому. Таких глаголов на самом деле больше изучаемых в школе, но остальные по разным причинам (чаще всего - ударение на окончании) не представляют сложностей.

**Разноспрягаемые глаголы** имеют личные формы единственного числа, характерные для первого спряжения, а множественного - для второго (это в русском языке, вообще термин шире).
Таких глаголов немного: хотеть, бежать и приставочные производные.

Ну и стоит упомянуть о неправильных глаголах: дать, есть и быть, имеющих особые личные формы. Последий, глагол быть, в русском вообще стоит особняком, но раньше он имел полную парадигму уникальных личных форм.

И последнее замечание. Первое-второе спряжение не есть что-то идущее от сути языка, это не более чем удобная запоминалка для школьников. Полная же система парадигм спряжений должна учитывать массу особенностей вплоть до особенностей прошедшего времени (протетитческий л, например, в любить - любЛю). А причина такого разнообразия - в том, что на разнообразие древнерусских спряжений (от четырёх до семи по различной систематике, не считая неправильных) наложились фонетические процессы X-XIX веков. Так что сведение к двум типам спряжения - очень условно.

Comment: А в чем разница между разноспрягаемыми глаголами (бежать, хотеть) от глаголов-исключений(брить, стелить, терпеть, вертеть, обидеть, зависеть, ненавидеть, видеть, смотреть)?

Comment: Я вам ответил в тексте своего основнового ответа.

Comment: Действительно, 2 спряжения глаголов - это по сути запоминалка для школьников. Иностранцам в курсе РКИ дают больше информации: по образованию глагольные формы распадаются на две группы в зависимости от образующей основы, которая может выступать в двух вариантах: как основа неопределенной формы и как основа настоящего времени.
Соотношение основы неопределенной формы и основы настоящего времени определяет деление глаголов на классы. Классы могут быть продуктивными (их 5) и непродуктивными (их больше). Для носителей языка эта информация лишняя. Но иногда ею нужно пользоваться во избежание ошибок.

Comment: Мне больше нравится подход РКИ-шников. Он всё-таки завязан на суть явления, а не на внешние проявления. 
Хотя пять классов - это что-то маловато будет. Это, правда, смотря как продуктивность считать... Помнится, у Аванесова девять продуктивных классов, а у Зализняка - и того больше.

Comment: Под словом "спряжение" в грамматике кто-то понимает любое формообразование глагола, в том числе изменение по родам, а кто-то считает, что спряжение - это изменение глаголов по лицам и числам (т.е. в настоящем и будущем времени). Поэтому и у нас здесь среди ответов и комментариев некоторая нестыковка получилась...

Answer (score 2):

> 

> Действительно, 2 спряжения глаголов - это по сути запоминалка для школьников.

Почему же только для школьников? Ведь помимо разноспрягаемых глаголов *бежать, хотеть*, глаголов особого спряжения *есть и дать* все остальные замечательно делятся на две группы: или в личном окончании буква И, или Е (соответственно во множественном числе или УТ(ЮТ), или АТ(ЯТ). Никаких "третьих", "четвертых" вариантов нет.

```
> Ведь на сколько я понимаю, спряжение глагола Бежать первое,
```

А как Вы вообще спряжение определяете? Почему Вы решили, что бежать - глагол первого спряжения? Потому что инфинитив на-ать? Так рассуждать нельзя. Это не приведет к правильному решению. Лететь - на ЕТЬ. Но это глагол второго спряжения.

Если личное окончание ударное, спряжение определяется по ударному окончанию: летИт, летЯт - второе спряжение. ИдЁт. идУт - первое, БежИт. бегУт - разноспрягаемое (окончание и первого, и второго спряжения). И только если окончание безударное, спряжение определяется по инфинитиву.

> А в чем разница между разноспрягаемыми глаголами (бежать, хотеть) от глаголов-исключений(брить, стелить, терпеть, вертеть, обидеть, зависеть, ненавидеть, видеть, смотреть)?

Вот в этом и разница. Брить, стелить - имеют окончания первого спряжения, 7 на -еть и 4 на-ать - -окончания второго спряжения, а разноспрягаемые глаголы имеют как окончания первого, так и окончания второго спряжения.

P.S. Я употребляю термин "спряжение " в узком смысле - как изменение глагола по лицам и числам в настоящем и будущем времени изъявительного наклонения.

Answer (score 0):

В школе к разноспрягаемым глаголам относят четыре: "хотеть", "есть", "бежать", "дать".

Comment: Ну пусть так. Непринципиально.
Хотя если судить по моей ссылке, это тоже не единый подход.

Answer (score 0):

всё-таки непонятно, почему слово "бежать" не включено в те одиннадцать глаголов- исключений.... Этот глагол ведь спрягается на -и. Так же слово "храпеть" тоже спрягается на -и, но его в исключении нет

Comment: В школьный список т.н. глаголов-исключений включены только те глаголы, в которых можно сделать ошибку (в личных формах, реже- в инфинитиве), поскольку "сомнительная" гласная не находится под ударением. К сожалению, о том, что глаголов, спрягаемых подобным образом, много больше, в школе обычно "забывавают" сообщить.

Answer (score 0):

Если сразу поставить глагол из инфинитивной формы в форму множественного числа ОНИ, то в 99 % случаев вы правильно определяете спряжение глагола. Если окончание ут/ют, то это 1-е спряжение, ат/ят — 2-е спряжение. Популярные разноспрягаемые глаголы, которые совмещают 1-е и 2-е спряжение, можно запомнить.

Answer (score -3):

В русском языке не два спряжения, а намного больше. Те два, которые известны со школы, нужны для чисто утилитарных целей: чтобы не допускать ошибок в написании окончаний. Применительно к слову «бежать» вероятность их появления исключена, потому что ударение падает на последний слог.

Comment: Очень путано и некорректно.
Что вы называете склонениями, которых "много больше", непонятно.
Ударение здесь совершенно ни при чем. Это явление совершенно другого порядка, обусловленное чередованием Г/Ж.

Comment: Для меня формальный показатель спряжения (обратите внимание на правильное написание этого слова) — определённые окончания разных глаголов при использовании их в конкретных формах (прежде всего, в зависимости от лица, числа, времени и наклонения). 

Я пояснил автору вопроса, что практическая значимость спряжений состоит в том, чтобы не путаться с окончаниями. И что в данном случае (ввиду очевидности написания) практическая же необходимость определения спряжения отпадает.

Что из сказанного Вам непонятно? или с чем Вы не согласны?

Comment: За "склонение" - извините, только это не "написание", а механическая ошибка.     

>>>Для меня формальный показатель спряжения...
Конкретнее можно? Как именно вы группирируте глаголы по спряжениям?
Вот, скажем, глаголы, отличающиеся только формой инфинитива, относятся к разным спряжениям?
Вообще двух глаголов с полностью совпадающми показателями во всех словоформах - ещё поискать надо. Так что, каждому глаголу отдельное спряжение будем посвещать?

Comment: >>>Я пояснил автору вопроса, что практическая значимость спряжений состоит в том, чтобы не путаться с окончаниями.  
    
Не думаю, что "автор вопроса" этого не знал до вашего разъяснения.
Но вы говорите о школьной ситеме спряжений, которую тут же и дискредитируете, заявив, что на самом деле спряжений "много больше".

>>>И что в данном случае (ввиду очевидности написания) практическая же необходимость определения спряжения отпадает.  
  
Исходите из того, что если автор спрашивает, то ему не очевидно.
Пока не очевидно, что "автор" - тролль.